# SOAP for game networking

Tags: http, networking, soap

I want to create a turn based game. I want to know if I can use SOAP for my networking.

1- Does the game need to request each time to get the new state of the game? Or is there any way to keep responding to all clients from the server?

2- Will a host ban me because of heavy load. for example some hundred requests per second (the requests have a very small size).